# dnsmasq different replies based on source

Tags: iptables, dnsmasq

I want to override the DNS configuration for some domains by using dnsmasq so that queries are forwarded elsewhere to be resolved. I can do this with this configuration snippet:

```
 server=/msecnd.net/10.0.0.10
 server=/samsungotn.net/10.0.0.10
 server=/samsungcloudsolution.net/10.0.0.10
```

The problem is - I only want/need this override for a particular client in my LAN (my smart TV) and I'd like to have regular DNS solve the same query for all other clients.

I'd like to ask if dnsmasq supports such a configuration, because I couldn't find a way by reading its manual (maybe I'm missing something or searching for the wrong terms).

An alternative way to solve it would be to do this:

1. create an iptables INPUT rule that matches the source I need to rewrite/mangle the destination UDP port to 53053 for example
2. run a different dnsmasq instance listening on port 53053 with the required config
3. profit.

However, although it should work, it seems convoluted and requires me to set up extra startup scripts.

I was hoping for a cleaner/easier way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this on my setup but only using NAT/port redirection iptables rules. In some respects, this is actually a more elegant method as iptables supports matching on the source MAC address of the client making the DNS query, which will still catch the client even if its IP address changes.

Your suggested method is the way I would do things. It does mean running two or more instances of dnsmasq, but I see no alternative as dnsmasq does not support this kind of functionality.

Comment: Thank you for confirming there's no way to do it in a single instance. I'll go the iptables route then.

Comment: @Mad_Ady Seems you can do this: 

http://serverfault.com/questions/509388/per-client-dns-servers-with-dnsmasq

However, this does not force clients to use particular name servers. It merely presents them with the ones they should use upon making a DHCP request. This may work for you, but if you really want to force a client to use specific DNS servers (either another dnsmasq instance or alternative online ones), the iptables route is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using two instance of dnsmasq, and if you can have them listening on different IPs, then you can use DHCP to assign different DNS to different clients, so you don't have to mess with iptables.